# scrollTop scrolls to appropriate spot then goes back to the top

Tags: jquery, dom, scroll

I'm trying to read a parameter in the URL, make a bunch of `display: none` content fade in, then scroll down to the appropriate point in the content.

Everything works until it scrolls down. It gets to the right spot, then inexplicably, it jumps to the top of the page again. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

The URL will be something like http://mydotcom/mystory/?page=mypage

The HTML will have a bunch of intro stuff, then a lot of text blocks with the class `.story`:

```
<div class="screen story" id="block1" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="container-text">
       some stuff here

    </div>
</div>
<div class="screen story" id="mypage" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="container-text">
        some more stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

The .story class has `display:none` in it and is `position: relative`.

When you come to the page, I want the code to parse the URL, get the parameter, make the .story content appear, then scroll down to the appropriate text block:

```
    //function to parse URL parameters
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
                }
            }

        };

        var page = getUrlParameter('page'); //get the parameter
        if ((page !== "") && (page !== undefined) ){ //if the parameter exists and has a value
            $(".story").fadeIn(); //fade in all the story blocks
            $('html,body').delay( 800 ).animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + page).offset().top //scroll down to the block specified
            }, 1000);

        }
```

Again, what happens is the content appears, the scroll down works, then it jumps back to the top of the page.

Comment: What triggers your scroll code?

Comment: @Eldar - just if a parameter is in the URL. Sometimes one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is due to not canceling the "link". So when you click link on your site it could restart website after javascript.

So when you would use event listener to catch when your link is clicked and then use something like `e.preventDefault()` or event listener would `return false`. That's how you would emulate link without firing it.

I could be wrong but

Other reason could be `fadeIn()` and `scrollTop: $("#" + page).offset().top` so calculation could be wrong due to the elements that were hidden. So offset would be calculated without elements that are hided. I can see that there is `delay(800)` but maybe `fadeIn` lasts more...

Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: Thank you, @sonic!

Comment: np :) What is the answer ?

Comment: Yes I see. I ment if what was causing the problem was not canceling the link or it was `fadeIn()`